# How to solve an integral like $\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) dI(y_i<t)$

Tags: statistics, integration

how can I solve an integral of the following type:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\; \text{d}\,I(y_i<t),$$
where $I(y_i<t)=1$ if $y_i<t$ and $0$ oterhrwise.

In particular I'm interested in the case of $f(t)=t\log t$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable meaning this sum can have is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nf(y_i).
$$